# How to Select multiple range with ClosedXML?

Tags: c#, closedxml

I need to select multiple range using ClosedXML

```
test = worksheet.Range(1 , 1, 10, 1).Cells(true)
```

I need to get from row 1, column 1 to row 10 column 1 but also  row 15, column 1 to row 20 column 1

I tried to do the following but nothing work:

```
test = worksheet.Range(1 , 1, 10, 1, 15,1,20,1).Cells(true)
test = worksheet.Range(1 , 1, 10, 1).Range(15,1,20,1).Cells(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you may need the `Ranges` property. In my small test, using the two ranges you defined worked by simply coloring the background cells. Example…

```
var wbook = new XLWorkbook(@"C:\PathToExcel_File\Book1.xlsx");
var worksheet = wbook.Worksheet(1);
var test2 = worksheet.Ranges("A1:A10, A15:A20");
test2.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.LightGreen;
```

Defining the range with four (4) parameters will not work as you have tried and you will have to use the Alpha column name (A,B,C…) because each `Range` defined in the `Ranges` is separated by a comma. In my small tests, this worked as expected.